# Java 9 HttpClient still in incubation?

Tags: java, post, multipartform-data, java-9, java-http-client

Saw from Javadoc of [`HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpClient.html) -

> Incubating Feature. Will be removed in a future release.

And it doesn't seem to support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` **POST**. See this post:

[Java 9 HttpClient send a multipart/form-data request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392160/java-9-httpclient-send-a-multipart-form-data-request)

Comment: @nullpointer , can you give an example to POST an HTML form like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` , with Java 9 HttpClient ?

Comment: @nullpointer not conclusion. Just seems to.

Comment: Clearing all of my personal opinions though to not make a mess out here. But I am voting to close this unless this has got some research attached to it as Off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP/2 Client ([JEP 110](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/110)) is still in incubation for JDK 9. See [JDK-8170648](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170648):

> Standardizing the API will be deferred to a future release. The API will be included in JDK 9 as an incubating feature ( see incubator modules [JDK-8169768](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8169768)).

In this [comment of JDK-8042950](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8042950?focusedCommentId=13963593&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13963593) you can find some reasons why it was deferred.

About the content type support: You *can* set any MIME type you like, but there does not seem to be any encoders that will produce a particular body format. In other words, it possible to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` but you have to encode the body in the correct format yourself, by implementing a [BodyProcessor](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpRequest.BodyProcessor.html) like in the linked answer.

It could be that they'll more add body processors in the future (though the proposal page says the API is supposed to stay very minimal) but for now I would probably just switch to a more feature-rich client or take adopt the body encoder from an existing library to make it work with the HTTP/2 client.

Comment: Could you support the fact *And it doesn't seem to support application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data POST* please.