# Java 11 - HttpClient - JIRA - FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException

Tags: file-upload, jira, java-11, jira-rest-api, java-http-client

Im trying to upload a file to a JIRA task using the Java 11 HttpClient.
But getting org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/octet-stream

```
public static java.net.http.HttpResponse<String> postFileNew(String url, String file, Map<String, String> headers) {

    Path filePath = Paths.get(file);
    HttpRequest request;
    HttpClient httpClient;
    java.net.http.HttpResponse<String> response;

    HttpRequest.Builder builder = HttpRequest.newBuilder();
    headers.forEach(builder::header);

    try {     
      request = builder
            .uri(URI.create(url))          
            .POST(null == file ? HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody() :
                    HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofFile(filePath))
            .build();

        httpClient = getHttpClient(getSslContext());
        response = httpClient.send(request, java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        if(null != response) {
            System.out.println("response status code - " + response.statusCode());
            System.out.println("response body - " + response.body());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {     
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
}
```

Im passing the following headers,

```
private static void uploadTestsToJira() throws IOException {
    String fileLocation = "C:\\Users\\username\\git\\project\\src\\main\\resources\\Files\\Hello.txt";
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    
    String authorizationValue = ParameterStore.getBasicAuthValueFromParameterStore("/proj/projAcct", ",");
    headers.put("Authorization", authorizationValue);
    headers.put("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
  
   java.net.http.HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = Utilities.postFileNew("https://jira-url/rest/api/2/issue/issue-id/attachments",
            fileLocation, headers); 
}
```

Getting the below Exception,
Below is the complete stack trace,

```
response status code - 500
response body - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><status><status-code>500</status-code><message>org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/octet-stream</message><stack-trace>java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/octet-stream
    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.multipart.fileupload.CommonsFileUploadMultipartHandler.getForm(CommonsFileUploadMultipartHandler.java:78)
    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.multipart.jersey.MultipartFormMessageBodyReader.readFrom(MultipartFormMessageBodyReader.java:36)
    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.multipart.jersey.MultipartFormMessageBodyReader.readFrom(MultipartFormMessageBodyReader.java:25)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.AdaptingContainerRequest.getEntity(AdaptingContainerRequest.java:236)
    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.multipart.jersey.MultipartFormDispatchProvider$1.getInjectableValues(MultipartFormDispatchProvider.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(DispatchProviderHelper.java:129)
    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(DispatchProviderHelper.java:178)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at 
.
.
.

    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.mywork.client.filter.ServingRequestsFilter.doFilter(ServingRequestsFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.mobile.web.filter.MobileAppRequestFilter.doFilter(MobileAppRequestFilter.java:59)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.mobile.login.MobileLoginSuccessFilter.doFilter(MobileLoginSuccessFilter.java:54)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.UniversalAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(UniversalAnalyticsFilter.java:75)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:33)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:80)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:51)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKillerFilter.doFilter(BotKillerFilter.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MobileAppRequestFilter.doFilter(MobileAppRequestFilter.java:36)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.executeRequest(AccessLogFilter.java:93)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.pagebuilder.PageBuilderFilter.doFilter(PageBuilderFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.doFilter(CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.oauth2.scopes.web.ReadWriteScopeFilter.doFilter(ReadWriteScopeFilter.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.ratelimiting.internal.filter.RateLimitFilter.doFilter(RateLimitFilter.java:73)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.troubleshooting.thready.filter.AbstractThreadNamingFilter.doFilter(AbstractThreadNamingFilter.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.xsrf.XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.doFilter(XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MauEventFilter.doFilter(MauEventFilter.java:49)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(JiraSecurityFilter.java:66)
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:242)
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.doFilter(JiraSecurityFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:148)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:77)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:38)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.pats.web.filter.TokenBasedAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TokenBasedAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.oauth2.provider.core.web.AccessTokenFilter.doFilter(AccessTokenFilter.java:81)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.johnson.JiraJohnson503Filter.doFilter(JiraJohnson503Filter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.doFilter(CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.java:30)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.plugins.authentication.impl.basicauth.filter.DisableBasicAuthFilter.doFilter(DisableBasicAuthFilter.java:70)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.JiraAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(JiraAnalyticsFilter.java:30)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:33)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.ratelimiting.internal.filter.RateLimitPreAuthFilter.doFilter(RateLimitPreAuthFilter.java:71)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.troubleshooting.thready.filter.AbstractThreadNamingFilter.doFilter(AbstractThreadNamingFilter.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.LocationCleanerFilter.doFilter(LocationCleanerFilter.java:36)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:31)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.encoding.AbstractEncodingFilter.doFilter(AbstractEncodingFilter.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.PathMatchingEncodingFilter.doFilter(PathMatchingEncodingFilter.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.doFilter(MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.MetricsCollectorFilter.doFilter(MetricsCollectorFilter.java:25)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraFirstFilter.doFilter(JiraFirstFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:121)
    at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(StuckThreadDetectionValve.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/octet-stream
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.&lt;init&gt;(FileUploadBase.java:948)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)
    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.multipart.fileupload.CommonsFileUploadMultipartHandler.getForm(CommonsFileUploadMultipartHandler.java:72)
    ... 273 more
```

Could anybody please tell me as to how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: " the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/octet-stream "

You need to format the request body to conform to what your server expects: in this case it seems to expect a multipart form.
 
The java 11 HttpClient doesn't do that out of the box.

This question has already come in the past - see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481475/how-to-define-multiple-parameters-for-a-post-request-using-java-11-http-client/56482187#56482187)

Comment: @daniel - i have tried using that solution as well. With that i get Response code as 200, but the Response body as [ ]. But the file does not get uploaded to the Jira task.

Comment: Then I would suggest turning on logging on the server side to try and figure out what the issue is.
You could also pass `-Djdk.httpclient.HttpClient.log=errors,requests,headers` on the client side to see what headers are included in the request/response.